# Append data to multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a list of strings and I want to append this strings to a multidimensional numpy array. My simplified code look like this:

```
c = np.array([])
liste = ['1', '2', '3']

while True:
    for i in range(0,len(liste)): 
        c = np.append(c, int(liste[i]), axis=i)
```

But I'm running into this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

So the first value of the list should always be appended to the first axis of the NumPy array, the second value of the list to the second axis and so on

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: i edit my question, hope its more clear now

Comment: What is the point of while True here? You want to infinitely keep adding the elements? How come there are 4 elements in each?

Comment: this is just to simplify my code. In my original code im getting live data of an arduino as a list of values and I want to plot each data values. So my idea was to save each data point in an axis of a NumPy array and then plot each axis separately

Comment: Do not use `np.append`, especially not in a loop.  Use lists and list append

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do -

```
np.repeat(liste, n).reshape(len(liste),n)
```

```
array([['1', '1', '1', '1'],
       ['2', '2', '2', '2'],
       ['3', '3', '3', '3']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
c = np.empty((4,3))
c[:] = list(map(int,liste))
c = c.T

print(c)
#[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
# [2. 2. 2. 2.]
# [3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

Comment: that's cool. But I expect that my list is gonna chance over time. can I add this new list to this existing array?

Comment: @BeneKunz what do you mean by 'add'? as new rows?

Comment: in the same row: like my list is changing to liste = ['4', '5', '6'] and than append this to the array so that the output is: [[1. 1. 1. 1. 4.] [2. 2. 2. 2. 5.] [3. 3. 3. 3. 6.]]

Answer (score 0):

The full traceback for your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-141-d8b64ceac809>", line 6, in <module>
    c = np.append(c, int(liste[i]), axis=i)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4671, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

`np.append` (with axis specified) has just passed the task on to `np.concatenate`.  That's the basic function for joining arrays.  But it is picky about dimensions.

You are trying join an array (1d) and a scalar:

```
In [142]: c
Out[142]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [143]: c.shape
Out[143]: (0,)
In [144]: int(liste[i])
Out[144]: 1
```

Removing that `axis` (and the `while):

```
In [146]: c = np.array([])
     ...: liste = ['1', '2', '3']
     ...: for i in range(0,len(liste)):
     ...:     c = np.append(c, int(liste[i]))
In [147]: c
Out[147]: array([1., 2., 3.])
```

which is just the same as making an array from the list (float because of how `c` was initialized.

```
In [148]: np.array(liste, dtype=int)
Out[148]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`np.append` is a poorly named and conceived function.  Don't use it.

I think you were trying to imitate a list append:

```
In [149]: c = []
     ...: liste = ['1', '2', '3']
     ...: for i in range(0,len(liste)):
     ...:     c.append(int(liste[i]))
In [150]: c
Out[150]: [1, 2, 3]
```

But to make 3 copies, you need something like:

```
In [154]: [liste for i in range(3)]
Out[154]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
In [155]: np.array([liste for i in range(3)], dtype=int)
Out[155]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

(list comprehension usually can replace for loops with append).

That array can be easily transposed.

Or throwing in a list transpose first:

```
In [161]: np.array(list(zip(*[liste for i in range(4)])),int)
Out[161]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```